# HTML CSS Установить размер внутреннего div в зависимости от размера внешнего

Tags: html, css

У меня есть div, внутри которого три div'a установленных вертикально. И я хочу к примеру сделать первый блок 25% от ширины внешнего div, второй 25% и третий 50%. Можно ли как-то с помощью CSS сделать это?

```
<div id="ribbblock">
<div class="row">
<a>
  <div id="first" style="text-align: left; width: 100%;">

  </div>
</a>
<a>

  <div id="second" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">

  </div>
</a>
<a>

  <div id="third" style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">

  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex; /* optional */
  padding: 20px;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.block:nth-child(1),
.block:nth-child(2) { width: 25%; }

.block:nth-child(3) { width: 50%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">25%</div>
  <div class="block">25%</div>
  <div class="block">50%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличное решение, помогло! Спасибо большое ;)

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич, не за что, желаю успехов!